# How do I upgrade Non-Readable replica to readable (active) replica in Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure

We have a Azure SQL Database with one read-only replica. We want to upgrade it to a plan that makes the replica active, so that it becomes readable.

However, the upgrade procedure produces the following error:

> Database scale operation from S1 Standard to P1 Premium failed for theDb.
>   ErrorCode: undefined ErrorMessage: The operation cannot be performed since the database 'theDb' is in a replication relationship.

Which is understandable. But I am not sure in which order to du stuff without loosing data or having to restore everything from scratch.

In which order am I supposed to do stuff here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to change your database from Standard to premium you will have to remove the replica first then change to premium, then add the new online (Read-Only) replica. Right now you have got a Standard tier database you will have a Online (Non-Readable) replica if you change to Premium you be able to add an online (Read-Only) replica.

I am a cautious fellow and would always make sure I back things up before making big changes.